# MATLAB Preferences: display variable values when hovering

Tags: matlab

Where is the option to display the variables values when hovering the variable with the cursor? I've been looking for it, but I can't find it.

[image]

Comment: Can you precise the version of Matlab you are running please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find the option in your preferences, Editor/Debugger subgroup, then Display.

The option is called "Enable datatips in edit mode"

Cheers,

S.P.

Comment: Thank you! It is a very useful option